# install an apk from a local file

Tags: java, android

I made an application where I download an APK from an internal server, save it locally and want to prompt the user to install it.
My code is the following:

```
        Button bt_install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install_bt);
        bt_install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadNewVersion().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    class DownloadNewVersion extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            bar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            bar.setCancelable(false);
            bar.setMessage("Downloading...");
            bar.setIndeterminate(true);
            bar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            bar.show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            bar.setIndeterminate(false);
            bar.setMax(100);
            bar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            String msg = "";
            if(progress[0]>99){
                msg="Finishing... ";
            }else {
                msg="Downloading... "+progress[0]+"%";
            }
            bar.setMessage(msg);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            bar.dismiss();
            if(result){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Update Done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Boolean flag = false;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://androidpala.com/tutorial/app-debug.apk");
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file,"app-debug.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                int total_size = 1431692;//size of apk
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                int per = 0;
                int downloaded=0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    downloaded +=len1;
                    per = (int) (downloaded * 100 / total_size);
                    publishProgress(per);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                OpenNewVersion(PATH);
                flag = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + e.getMessage());
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }
    void OpenNewVersion(String location) {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Download/"+"app-debug.apk";
        Uri fileLoc = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileLoc, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }




}
```

The path has the file of the APK so no problem with the download but when trying to launch the activity get Update Error .

What am I doing wrong here?

logcot

```
11-30 14:30:54.075 5380-5380/net.amjadroid.fonts E/Zygote: v2
11-30 14:30:54.075 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10342
11-30 14:30:54.075 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
11-30 14:30:54.075 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
11-30 14:30:54.076 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.1.1_0001, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
11-30 14:30:54.076 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=net.droid5d.myapp 
11-30 14:30:54.079 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-30 14:30:54.148 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/ActivityThread: performLaunchActivity: mActivityCurrentConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 422mcc2mnc [ar_AE,en_US] ldrtl sw411dp w411dp h773dp 560dpi nrml long port ?dc finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h mkbd/h desktop/d s.8}
11-30 14:30:54.153 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-30 14:30:54.182 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:54.183 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:54.188 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:54.200 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
11-30 14:30:54.203 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=69
11-30 14:30:54.203 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: setView = DecorView@aa21a73[SplashScreen] touchMode=true
11-30 14:30:54.208 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
11-30 14:30:54.225 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
11-30 14:30:54.225 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 529685839872} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
11-30 14:30:54.225 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 529685839872} hwInitialized=true
11-30 14:30:54.259 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
11-30 14:30:54.274 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-30 14:30:54.274 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-30 14:30:54.278 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2960]-format:1
11-30 14:30:54.303 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=١
11-30 14:30:54.303 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
11-30 14:30:54.303 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 529685839872}
11-30 14:30:54.304 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@49264c7 nm : net.droid5d.myapp ic=null
11-30 14:30:54.304 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
11-30 14:30:54.310 5380-5400/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
11-30 14:30:54.313 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5f3baf4 nm : net.droid5d.myapp ic=null
11-30 14:30:55.666 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-30 14:30:55.775 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-30 14:30:55.800 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
11-30 14:30:55.814 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/ActivityThread: performLaunchActivity: mActivityCurrentConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 422mcc2mnc [ar_AE,en_US] ldrtl sw411dp w411dp h773dp 560dpi nrml long port ?dc finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h mkbd/h desktop/d s.8}
11-30 14:30:55.824 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.824 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.828 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
11-30 14:30:55.830 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.832 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.833 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.835 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.835 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:55.846 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
11-30 14:30:55.848 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=84
11-30 14:30:55.848 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@f6ce7d8[MainActivity] touchMode=true
11-30 14:30:55.850 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
11-30 14:30:55.874 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
11-30 14:30:55.875 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 529815250432} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
11-30 14:30:55.875 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 529815250432} hwInitialized=true
11-30 14:30:55.877 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2960]-format:1
11-30 14:30:55.877 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
11-30 14:30:55.906 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=١
11-30 14:30:55.906 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
11-30 14:30:55.906 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 529815250432}
11-30 14:30:55.907 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2b0f233 nm : net.droid5d.myapp ic=null
11-30 14:30:55.907 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
11-30 14:30:55.917 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=81
11-30 14:30:55.917 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=79
11-30 14:30:55.974 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7b5b67dc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7b53a971e0
11-30 14:30:55.974 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
11-30 14:30:55.978 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@3cea6e2[SplashScreen]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
11-30 14:30:56.370 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-30 14:30:56.479 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-30 14:30:56.485 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:56.492 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
11-30 14:30:56.494 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:56.496 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
11-30 14:30:56.498 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:56.499 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:56.500 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
11-30 14:30:56.503 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
11-30 14:30:56.506 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=76
11-30 14:30:56.506 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@e541050[MainActivity] touchMode=true
11-30 14:30:56.507 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
11-30 14:30:56.509 5380-5442/net.droid5d.myapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
11-30 14:30:56.510 5380-5442/net.droid5d.myapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-30 14:30:56.510 5380-5442/net.droid5d.myapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-30 14:30:56.513 5380-5442/net.droid5d.myapp D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
11-30 14:30:56.524 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
11-30 14:30:56.525 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[37,1235][1403,1641] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 529685839872} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
11-30 14:30:56.525 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 529685839872} hwInitialized=true
11-30 14:30:56.526 5380-5408/net.droid5d.myapp D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1590x630]-format:1
11-30 14:30:56.526 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
11-30 14:30:56.526 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 529685839872}
11-30 14:30:56.536 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(37, 1235 - 1403, 1641) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=١
11-30 14:30:56.555 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
11-30 14:31:14.568 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-30 14:31:14.725 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-30 14:31:22.942 5380-5442/net.droid5d.myapp E/MainActivity: Update Error: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/app-debug.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
11-30 14:31:22.984 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
11-30 14:31:22.984 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@86b8613[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
11-30 14:31:22.997 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=76
11-30 14:31:22.998 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp W/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: Listener is null
11-30 14:31:23.019 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
11-30 14:31:23.020 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 529815250432}
11-30 14:31:23.022 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
11-30 14:31:23.039 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
11-30 14:31:23.040 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@89d4f57[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{d717a44 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
11-30 14:31:23.040 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/Toast: Text: Frro in android.widget.Toast$TN@129f72d
11-30 14:31:23.045 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@89d4f57[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
11-30 14:31:23.072 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
11-30 14:31:23.073 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@89d4f57[Toast]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[443,2407][996,2568] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 529685839872} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
11-30 14:31:23.075 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@89d4f57[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(443, 2407 - 996, 2568) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=١
11-30 14:31:25.028 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@89d4f57[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
11-30 14:31:25.040 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=80
11-30 14:31:25.040 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp W/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: Listener is null
11-30 14:31:55.035 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1fc2462 nm : net.droid5d.myapp ic=null
11-30 14:31:55.035 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
11-30 14:31:55.038 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
11-30 14:31:55.039 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81
11-30 14:32:00.732 5380-5380/net.droid5d.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@65a66bb[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
```

Comment: You need to print stacktrash

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: done print stacktrash

Comment: I will not use asyncTask for downloading big files. The activity can very well be destroyed before download completed.

Comment: small file .. 1MB

Comment: You should call OpenNewVersion in onPostExecute. Further you do not have to show us your asynctask or download code as we will believe that you manage to download the apk to a file on your storage. So only posting OnNewVersion() would have done.

Comment: `Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + e.getMessage());`. And.. What is the message?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Broadcast Receiver:

```
//broadcast receiver to get notification about ongoing downloads
    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
            long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
                try {
                    //start the installation of the latest version
                    Uri uri;
                    Cursor q = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadReference));
                    if ( q == null ) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "FAILED: Unable to read downloaded file" ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    q.moveToFirst();
                    String path = "file://" + q.getString(q.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                    uri = Uri.parse(path);

                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, downloadManager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadReference));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    if (intent != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App download failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

For Register Broadcast for download :

```
//Broadcast receiver for the download manager
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
```

And Download asyncTask like:

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;

    class DownloadApkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            File file = new File(String.valueOf(downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference)));
            file.delete();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage(MessageConstant.LOADING);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(loginResponse.getAppUpgradeUrl());
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                if (AppUtil.isConnectedMobile()) {
                    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                } else if (AppUtil.isConnectedWifi()) {
                    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
                }
                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
                request.setTitle("App Download");
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "DemoApp.apk");
                downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "An error occured during download. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: all steps are above. register broadcast in oncreate, then call asyncTask to download apk and once it is downloaded broadcastreciver onReceive method will call and it will install downloaded apk.

Comment: You have done this but the same error ..Can you write the full code?

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity: Update Error: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/app-debug.apk 
  exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

Is this on Android 7+ ?

If so then google for `FileUriExposedException` and use a `FileProvider`.